# Items not included SharePoint search results if a property missing

Tags: sharepoint, mssqlft

I use an MSSQLFT query to poll Sharepoint's search through `Search.asxm` web service.

The query goes like this:

```
SELECT PreferredName, Department, AccountName, MobilePhone, WorkPhone
       Title, JobTitle, OfficeNumber
FROM SCOPE()
WHERE 
     "scope"="People" AND JobTitle="Something"
ORDER BY
       Department, OfficeNumber
```

Some people do not have `Depmartment` attribute set and hence are not included in search results.
If I remove the "Department" part from "Order by" clause, everything works fine. Is there a way to provide "default value" for such missing property so that these people would still get included?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried including the Department field in the where.  You might have to hack it to say something like AND (dept = '' or dept not null). In other words, any value is acceptible.  That would get the rows included in the results so the Order By clause could operate on them.

Comment: That doesn't work unfortunately.  It would make sense though.